# Script code not working ( HTML) before id

Tags: javascript, html

Im relatively new to HTML and Javascript , Im currently in functions right now.
I tried this code but it didn't print anything. if I use a button and keep the document.get... inside a function it works why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Javasc"; 
</script>

<p>
hey
</p>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add head tag too. Also try to run your code after closing body tag.

Comment: @Princesodhi `head` tags may be omitted if the head is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your function on window.onload maybe. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Javasc";
        };

</script>

<p>
hey
</p>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

You have to let the page rendered and then call the method.

Or put the script tag at the end

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p>
hey
</p>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Javasc"; 
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, But it works even though i remove that window.onload().why is it working when i use function but not just the statement.

Comment: @dicedlithium Because that's how Javascript works. functions are called when needed rather than your code which ran as soon as the page loaded up to that point.